# Original data being transformed when called and not able to use original data when function called again

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. I am writing a function to do some calculations.

When I first call the function on load, the data is correct but then when I do an on('change'). The data instead of using the original data is performing the calculations based on loaded data.

I even re-assigned by data to a new variable.

This is my code:

```js
let data1 = [{date:'2018-01-01',device:'iphone',site:'google',val1:10,val2:20,val3:30},{date:'2018-01-01',device:'iphone',site:'bing',val1:23,val2:12,val3:14},{date:'2018-01-01',device:'iphone',site:'jeeves',val1:67,val2:78,val3:12},{date:'2018-01-01',device:'ipad',site:'google',val1:10,val2:20,val3:30},{date:'2018-01-01',device:'ipad',site:'bing',val1:23,val2:12,val3:14},{date:'2018-01-01',device:'ipad',site:'jeeves',val1:67,val2:78,val3:12},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'iphone',site:'google',val1:11,val2:22,val3:33},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'iphone',site:'bing',val1:25,val2:27,val3:28},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'iphone',site:'jeeves',val1:67,val2:80,val3:15},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'ipad',site:'google',val1:12,val2:21,val3:31},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'ipad',site:'bing',val1:26,val2:16,val3:11},{date:'2018-01-02',device:'ipad',site:'jeeves',val1:65,val2:79,val3:55},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'iphone',site:'google',val1:17,val2:19,val3:11},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'iphone',site:'bing',val1:13,val2:15,val3:12},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'iphone',site:'jeeves',val1:69,val2:79,val3:15},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'ipad',site:'google',val1:17,val2:51,val3:31},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'ipad',site:'bing',val1:25,val2:15,val3:17},{date:'2018-01-03',device:'ipad',site:'jeeves',val1:61,val2:71,val3:15}]
let key = 'val1'
let nums = ['val2', 'val3'];

const func = () => {
  let new_data = [];
  console.log(new_data)
  new_data = data1.filter(d => d['date'] <= '2018-01-02');
  console.log(new_data)
  new_data.forEach(d => nums.forEach(pa => d[pa] = d[pa] / d[key]));
}

func();

$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
  func();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='mySelect'>
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
  <option value='divide'>Divide</option>
  <option value='orig'>Original</option>
</select>
```

The problem is on change the data1 no contains the previous iteration's data.

Is there a way, when I always call the function, the original data1 is always used.

Comment: unrelated to the question asked, but you are comparing the strings of dates, this can give inaccurate results.

Comment: @EliteDaMyth, I am sorry, I don't know what you mean

Comment: in this part `d['date'] <= '2018-01-02'`, the `d['date']` is a string, and you are comparing it with another string.

Comment: The snippet in the question does not show the behaviour you describe.

Comment: @EliteDaMyth, I use moment.js in my original data which fixes that.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, on load the first object has the original data: `{
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "device": "iphone",
    "site": "google",
    "val1": 10,
    "val2": 20,
    "val3": 30
  }` and then on change the first object in the array of objects is: `{
    "date": "2018-01-01",
    "device": "iphone",
    "site": "google",
    "val1": 10,
    "val2": 2,
    "val3": 3
  }`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, `on change` the want the original data

Comment: That is not the behaviour I see in your snippet: https://i.imgur.com/85NCoTA.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, if you notice in your image, `val2` and `val3` is always different. When you call the function on load for the 0th object, `val2` is `2` and then on change `val2` is `0.2`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, everytime on change, I want the original data to be used not the previously calculated data

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, any luck why this is happening?

Comment: That's because your code is performing the calculation on those values every time the function is called...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, is there a way to avoid that and always use the original data on function call?